# Error "Result was not expanded automatically, please insert more rows": how to add rows automatically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use an `ImportRange` formula to get data from multiple tabs into single one. The formula looks like

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("123","B1!A2:D");IMPORTRANGE("123","B2!A2:D")},"where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

Is it there a way to add rows to table automatically if they are needed? With formula or setting - not by app script.

Comment: Two questions  1) In your table, do any of the cells below the QUERY formula have content in them  2) If not, is there a reason you can't add enough extra rows to the sheet to accommodate any possible length?

Comment: @KrispinMiller 1. No. 2. Not really. I want just know, whether i should. If there is no way to add needed rows by formula or any other GSheets functionality, i will add rows manually to the maximum before begin with `ImportRange`.

Comment: You can do with app script, but if you aren't familiar app script and javascript, it can be a bit difficult to learn and set up.   There isn't a large performance penalty for having blank rows at the bottom of the sheet, especially if they aren't referenced in array formulas.  You could just add 1,000 rows to the bottom (or some other large number based on your needs) and not have to maintain it.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information, clearly indicating the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem

Added another "arrayformula" to my original formula:

`=INDEX(QUERY(...))`

Made some tests and appeared all array-like formulas will add new rows automatically, including `query`. This means adding a new array function to your original formula will force the engine to recalculate again and add new rows. In general, this case looks like a bug / not expected behavior. The reason may be in the limit of resources the formula has, and it stops the work if calculations are heavy.

### Limit test: `Sequence`

This formula will work:

`=SEQUENCE(50500)`

This will produce an error:

`=SEQUENCE(50501)`

After you add a new row manually, the formula works again.

Adding new formulas like `INDEX(SEQUENCE(50501))` does not fix the error.

### Limit test: array-like functions

I've also tested these functions:

`QUERY`

`{Array}`

`SEQUENCE`

`Offset`

`Sort`

`Index`

`ArrayFormula`

All of them stopped working after row 50501 including.

### Possible Script solution

Possible to get the number of rows from the original formula.

`=ROWS(SEQUENCE(50501))`

Next, create a trigger to execute every N minutes to add new rows to your sheet.

### Source

- [My Sample file with tests](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z56sTQ5L9tZdDsD2r8Qq3_Fft0csoqsp0RuyWWnYX7E/edit#gid=164226591)

All tests were made by date and in my environment. Your own tests may vary.

Answer (score 1):

The sheet pulling the data (importrange) from another sheet does not have sufficient rows to display the data. Add more rows to the sheet - this solution worked for me. Ideally, this should have happened automatically, but it did not.
Refer:
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4985024/error-in-gsheets-result-was-not-expanded-automatically-please-insert-more-rows-4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).